# Linux: How to determine which console I am using

Tags: linux

I use Ubuntu 12.04.
I am logged-in to `tty2`, `tty1` and `tty7`.

In my textbook I read that the `whoami` command allows me to determine which console I am using. But this command merely shows my login. As for the command `who`, it always lists `tty2`, `tty1` and `tty7`. So, even the order of these consoles can't help me.

Could you help me how to determine the current console?

Comment: How about the `tty` command?

Comment: pls accept one of these answers so it won't show up as an unanswered question..

Answer (score 4):

Use `tty`

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Just remove the /dev/ and you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

current:

```
$ tty | sed -e "s:/dev/::"
```